# Obter dados por POST no ReactJS

Tags: javascript, post, react, react-router

Quando preciso capturar dados no ReactJS através de querystring, eu utilizo o comando `this.props.match.params.[NOME_DA_QUERY]`.

> Alguém sabe como faço pra capturar quando esses dados vêm por POST?

Comment: Cara, não recomendo utilizar o body de uma requisição via client-side, porém, se esse dado está vindo de um formulário, existe essa lib que te ajuda: https://github.com/insin/react-router-form

Comment: Eu não entendi a sua pergunta. Como que você está mandando dados via Post para o react?

Comment: @Francisco, muito obrigado pela dica, não conhecia essa biblioteca.

A solução que eu acabei tomando foi de: no keyup da imput do primeiro formulário, eu fui gravando os dados num localStorage. Lá no react, eu consigo pegar esses dados tranquilamente.

Comment: @GabrielArantes quando você diz: "dados vêem do post", está se referindo aos dados retornados quando através do front-end faz um requisição POST a uma API?